# ¿Cómo añadir una barra de deslizamiento cuando el contenido del div se sobreextienda? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente: Quiero que cuando haya mucho contenido en un div, en vez de que el div se haga mas grande añadirle un scroll bar. Os muestro una foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que en el div anterior aparezca un scroll bar cuando haya mucho contendió, ahora mismo lo que me hace es que el div en si se expande, y eso no lo quiero. HE probado a usar  y  pero no me funciona. Alguna idea?